# Django Validation Error

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to validate an uploaded image by implementing a file size restriction and a file extension.
The problem is when an image is upload , I want to validate the file size restriction and file extension before been process but I get this error

'member_descriptor' object is unsubscriptable

```
forms.py" in clean_image
  43.                         if not file.name[-3:].lower() in ['jpg']:

Exception Type: TypeError at /pro/
Exception Value: 'member_descriptor' object is unsubscriptable
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in _get_errors
  115.             self.full_clean()
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  270.         self._clean_fields()
```

My Forms.py

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean_image(self):
            cleaned_data = super(PersonForm,self).clean()
            image = cleaned_data.get("image")

            if image:
                    if image._size > 4*1024*1024:
                            raise forms.ValidationError("Image Must be <4mb Less")
                    if not file.name[-3:].lower() in ['jpg']:
                            raise forms.ValidationError("Your file extension was not recongized")
                    return image



class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = ('image',)
```

views.py

```
def pro(request):

    form = PersonForm()
    if request.POST.has_key('pro'):
        form = PersonForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if request.POST['pro'] == 'first':
            if form.is_valid():
                person = Person.objects.get(user=request.user)
                image = form.cleaned_data['image']

                if image:
                    person.image = form.cleaned_data['image']
                person.save()

    return render(request,'profile.html',{'form':form})
```

My models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that line where the exception is thrown, you try to access `file.name`. `file` is a built-in type in Python. That's what you are accessing there. You should try something like `if not image.file.name[-3:].lower() in ['jpg']:`.

Comment: The reason it worked when you split it up, because you had `def check_extension(file): if file.name[-3:].lower() in ['jpg']: return True else: return False`, that's not the case here.

Comment: @PauloBu I'd simply use `image.file.name.endswith('jpg')` like [PEP-8 recommends](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) or create a function like @BurhanKhalid suggested

Comment: Of course, I was just pointing that the `file` he was referring wasn't the actual field.